# Run selenium script that handles files remotely

Tags: python, json, docker, selenium, deployment

I'm using selenium in order to extract some data (as a json file). This json is the final output of the script.

I've managed to do it locally so far in two different ways:

- With a local webdriver (for Chrome).
- With a Docker container.

However, I need it to be accessible from anywhere, in systems that don't have either webdrivers/Docker installed.

I have thought about deploying the script to Heroku and work around that idea, but I have no idea how to handle the data in this situation.

Comment: Run locally on a webserver.  Your client can be a browser.

Comment: I've thought about it, but the files generated would stay on the server. What I need is that the output is exported to the server considering how it's done (I am not very familiar with the usage of webservers/clients, you may have a point). Could you elaborate on the comment please?

Comment: Also, it'd be better if the script could be executed not locally, as the place I'm running this is going to change a lot

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your requirements... but if the client doesn't have webdrivers available, that rules out using remote-webdrivers.  So just create an HTML-based interface available from a browser.  The server will run the scripts (this is what I meant by locally... the server would run the webdriver) and then send back a JSON file to the browser.  (simple http request/response to send file download...)

Answer (score 0):

I think that cloud services are meant for these situations.

A storage account ([S3](https://aws.amazon.com/es/s3/) in Amazon or Blob Storage for Azure) allows you to acces the data from anywhere, and without almost any limitation of space, using its API or by using their SDK's.
Also you can specify access policies if your data should not be publicly accessible.

As you have already developed your script into a Docker conatiner, your are ready to run it in almost every cloud provider (for example in Amazon [ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/es/ecr/)).